# Dom changes using javascript Cancels out Css

Tags: javascript, css, dom-manipulation

I am brand new to programming and javascript, and recently I tried practicing javascript with a website I created and whenever I declare any change in the DOM the website loses its css.

Example:

When I declare:

```
let "bodyTitle = document.getElementById('body1');

bodyTitle.textContent = 'Random TextContent';
```

I get the text changed but the CSS doesn't follow.

Did I just make faulty website structure or terrible css? I am still extremely new so I kind of threw things together to get my website.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Hey Ahmed, two things: Your missing code examples which make it hard to see what your doing wrong and this question would likely be better posted to SO (http://stackoverflow.com) as it doesn't seem related to SharePoint

Comment: thannks roland, i'll go check it out!